# TeXstudio: Don't autocomplete "content..." in block environments

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Each time I use autocompletion in TeXstudio for a block environment, e.g.

```
\begin{itemize}
content...
\end{itemize}
```

the "content..." is automatically inserted. Is it possible to disable that? It slows me down, because I need to delete it before filling in the contents of the block. I would like the autocomplete to produce just e.g.

```
\begin{itemize}
                        <-- Just a blank line here
\end{itemize}
```

A partial solution I found: Use CTRL+RIGHT to jump to the "content..." and overwrite it. But as I said, I would prefer not to have it there at all.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, please post it.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Currently (Apr 2020) this is hard coded in TeXstudio. See [related code lines](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/85d58cd14d56af4ffd22c55df464d6830cd32bdc/src/codesnippet.cpp#L261-L270). The code comment says `This is currently hard coded for the most common cases. Might become user-definable in the future (via addition to the snippet code (what would that imply for cwls?) or other means`. Maybe you can [open an issue](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues) under TeXstudio's GitHub repo.

Comment: @Augustin, If my answer does not answer your question somehow, please state why. Elsewise, you should accept it.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Good catch and good idea. I opened an issue: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1050.

Comment: @J.Schmidt Your solution is more of a workaround. Let's see what happens with the issue, maybe this will get fixed properly and the workaround won't be needed.

Answer (score 8):

You need to disable `insert arguments`

Go to Options > Configure TexStudio > Make sure that *Advanced Options* is checked > Completion > Uncheck `Insert arguments`

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem, but some other nice things stop working, e.g. the `\end{...}` is not properly autocompleted.

Answer (score 6):

Since it is not possible to obtain what you want, I found a way around the problem in some sense :

Start typing `\begin`, press Tab (not Enter !) when TexStudio proposes `\begin{*environment-name*}`. Then start typing your environment name, for example `proof`. When TexStudio proposes `\begin{proof}`, press Enter (not Tab !) and voila, you got yourself an environment without `content...` but also with the proper `\end{proof}` at the end.

Edit : if you still have **insert arguments** enabled in the options (see other answers) then `content...` will appear but it will be selected automatically so that when you type anything it will be replaced by what you write.

Comment: this is a better answer i think...

Answer (score 2):

In Options > Configure TexStudio > Menu > &Latex > &Environnements, one could change the "Generique" commande by this line :

```
\begin{%<environment-name%:id:1%>}%\%\\end{%<environment-name%:id:1,mirror%>}
```

So far, it doesn't affect other autocompletions.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for Macros that are defined as environments.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might affect some other autocompletions, but this can be done by using the menu Options/Configure TeXstudio/Completion and by disabling 'Use placeholders'.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem, but some other nice things stop working, e.g. the `\end{...}` is not properly autocompleted in some cases.